# Which book discusses metric topology in details?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Which book discusses metric topology in details? I have studied Topology from Munkres' book, and it discusses metric topology as particular cases of topological spaces. But I am looking for one which will give discussions on metric topology extensively and in greater details. Please suggest.

Comment: Any beginning book on analysis should do that. In fact, starting from metric spaces and abstracting away the metric to obtain topological spaces is, in my opinion, a more natural and intuitive development of the subject.

Comment: Chapter 2, if I remember correctly in Munkres' Topology discusses metric topology in quite detail. you might want to check it out.

Comment: I have seen it. But I am looking for a more extensive account.

Comment: These google searches give a lot of hits: [book search with "metric spaces" in title](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=intitle:%22metric+spaces%22) AND ["metric spaces" "amazon.com"](https://www.google.com/search?q="metric+spaces"+"amazon.com") AND ["metric spaces" "book"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22metric+spaces%22+%22book%22).